# Angular testing mock service function did not called

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, rxjs-observables

In my Angular project I have this Jasmine spec file:

```js
describe('TagListComponent', () => {
  let component: TagListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TagListComponent>;
  let debugElement: DebugElement;
  let models: Array<TagInterface> = hydrate.hydrateArray(TAGS);
  let paginate: PaginateInterface = new Paginate(Tag, models);
  const appDataService = new AppDataService(new Tag()) as 
    MockAppDataServiceInterface<TagInterface>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        DdataCoreModule.forRoot(environment),
        RouterTestingModule,
        AppModule,
      ],
      providers: [],
      declarations: [
        TagListComponent,
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents()
    .then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TagListComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      component.models = models;
      component.appDataService = appDataService;

      debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
      router = TestBed.inject(Router);

      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
  });

  describe('functions', () => {
    it('load', fakeAsync(() => {
      (component.appDataService.proxy as MockProxyServiceInterface<TagInterface>).fakePaginator = paginate;

      component.load();

      tick();

      expect((component.appDataService.proxy as MockProxyServiceInterface<TagInterface>).counter.getAll)
        .withContext(`getAll() should be called`)
        .toEqual(1);
    }));
  });
});
```

In the `AppDataService`:

```js
export class AppDataService<T extends BaseModelInterface<T>>
  implements MockAppDataServiceInterface<T>
{
  private readonly spinner: SpinnerServiceInterface;

  counter = {
    start: 0
  };

  proxy: MockProxyServiceInterface<T> = new ProxyService();

  helper: HelperServiceInterface<T>;

  constructor(private readonly model: T) {}

  start(pipeInstance: Observable<any>, spinnerName: string = 'spinner'): Observable<any> {
    this.counter.start++;

    return of(pipeInstance);
  }
}
```

In the `MockProxyService` I have this code:

```js
export class ProxyService<T extends BaseModelInterface<T>>
  extends MockObservableServiceAbstract
  implements MockProxyServiceInterface<BaseModelInterface<T>>
{
  counter = {
    getAll: 0,
  }

  fakePaginator: PaginateInterface;

  getAll(pageNumber?: number): Observable<PaginateInterface> {
    console.log('--------- This should be run');
    this.counter.getAll++;

    return of(this.fakePaginator);
  }
```

And in the component:

```js
export class TagListComponent implements OnInit {
  appDataService: AppDataServiceInterface<TagInterface> =
    new AppDataFactoryService<TagInterface>().get(Tag);
  getAll$ = this.appDataService.proxy
    .getAll(this.currentPageNumber)
    .pipe(map((result: PaginateInterface) => this.parseSearchResult(result)));

  load(): void {
    // ...
    this.subscriptions.add(this.loadDatas().subscribe());
  }

  loadDatas(): Observable<unknown> {
    // ...
    return this.appDataService.start(this.getAll$, 'load all post');
  }

  parseSearchResult(result: PaginateInterface): void {
    // ...
  }
}
```

When test running the `component.appDataService.start` has been called. This is good. The `component.appDataService.proxy.getAll()` should be called too, but didn't.

Any idea why didn't called the `...proxy.getAll()` function?

Comment: The `proxy.getAll()` should be called from `component.load();` in the test file?

Comment: @JosefKatič I think this is the call chain: `component.load()` -> `component.loadDatas()` -> `component.getAll$` -> `proxy.getAll()`. In the test he want to call only `compoent.load()` and expect to run all steps of the chain.